# Is there any way to use MetroFramework dlls in Java?

Tags: java, microsoft-metro

So I am trying to use the modern 'metro' look for java. I already have the [Metroframework dlls](https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/) since I have used it in my .Net apps.

Is it possible to use Metro in java so I can replace that 'oldish' look on it?

Comment: Not unless you really want to write your very own graphical framework. You should do some research and see if there's away for SWT to support it

Comment: So no? I cannot import those dlls?

Comment: Oh, I'm sure you import the DLLs, but getting to actually render anything on the screen, that's an entirely different (and way to broad) question

Comment: You, instead, using something JavaFX and it's CSS support to "fake" the look and feel [for example](https://pixelduke.wordpress.com/category/metro/), you have to remember, Metro is just a skin, it's an entirely different approach